# Android: Sticky Service not restarting

Tags: android, service, restart, sticky

My app uses a Service for background tasks. I want the Service to keep running when user kills the app(swipes it away). There are two scenario's in which the user kan kill the app:

```
Scenario 1: When in app:
    1 User presses **backbutton**, apps goes to background and user is on the homescreen.
    2 User presses the multitasking button and swips the app away.
    3 The Service should restart because its sticky.

Scenario 2: When in app:
    1 User presses **homebutton**, apps goes to background and user is on the homescreen.
    2 User presses the multitasking button and swips the app away.
    3 The Service should restart because its sticky.
```

Scenario 1 works exactly as expected. The Service restarts after the app is swiped away in a matter of seconds.

Scenario 2 does not work as expected. The service does get restarted but after more than 5 minutes.

I don't understand why it takes so long to restart the service in scenario 2. Is there a known solution to this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent test = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
        startService(test);
    }
}

public class TestService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("Service", "Service is restarted!");//In Scenario 2, it takes more than 5 minutes to print this. 
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: 100% working solution here -> try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51001246/3879847

Answer (score 0):

When you press the back button, you are essentially destroying the activity which means the `onDestroy()` is called where you `stop()` the `STICKY_SERVICE`. Hence the STICKY_SERVICE boots up again immediately.

When you press the home button, you are pausing the activity (`onPause()`), essentially putting it in background. The activity is only destroyed when the OS decides to GC it. It is only at that point of time that the `onDestroy()` is called at which you `stop()` the service and `STICKY_SERVICE` boots up again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But when i swipe the app away the onDestroy() is called. No matter in which scenario. In scenario 1 the service gets destroyed and restarts after seconds. In scenario 2 the service gets destroyed and restarts after minutes. This is a problem for me, I need the service to restart within seconds in bot scenario's because the code doesn't run for 5 minutes in scenario 2.