# How to always run a background service even application gets killed by user from background

Tags: android, android-service, android-5.0-lollipop

My Solution to write sticky service is working fine below Android version Lollipop but above Lollipop version service is getting closed when user kills the application from background.

Any suggestion guys.

Comment: Don't do it. It does not work for a reason.

Comment: you got to reschedule it using job schedular

Comment: This discussion may help you: [Android service not restarting in lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747624/android-service-not-restarting-in-lollipop)

Comment: for new APIs you can use this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49878237/2201814

Answer (score 2):

Use can start service as Foreground even os can't kill it for more info check link[Running a service in the foreground](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

Comment: But in case of foreground service we have to show service notification, that I don't want

Comment: You can hide that notification I am using it like this    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service).build();
        service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

Comment: try this method just pass it service name which you want to run as foreground private static void startForeground(Service service) {
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service).build();
        service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

Comment: like you can hide notification  startForeground(Yourservice.instance);
            startForeground(this);
            //Cancel this service's notification, resulting in zero notifications
            stopForeground(true);

Answer (score 1):

I got solution about it not why it's work for me but try this.

Override the onTaskRemoved()

```js
 @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Write your stuff which you set in onDestroy()
    }
```

and set same code which you set in onDestroy() it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For instance below code will work on Lollipop.

```
 @Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                this.getClass());
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePI);
}
```

But Things are getting quite tricky Since android N release. And now android O put some more restrictions on background tasks. So the thing in In Android O no background service can run the service will kill by OS just after your application gone from the foreground(Only Foreground services can run i.e Service with a notification on top). Here is a informative [solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pumf_4yjTMc).